# Custom login with no captcha recaptcha error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, recaptcha

I have created a custom login page but when the captcha is empty and the long is processed I am trying to get the error message `$error_message` to be passed onto it to `$error_msg`.

I am working with two wp plugins, one a no captcha recaptcha plugin and the other a client template portal.

The following is full code of the custom-login.php

```
<?php

class Ncr_Custom_Login_Captcha extends Ncr_No_Captcha_Recaptcha {

    public static function initialize() {

        // initialize if login is activated
        if ( isset(self::$plugin_options['captcha_login']) && self::$plugin_options['captcha_login'] == 'yes') {
            // add captcha header script to WordPress header
            add_action( 'wp_head', array( __CLASS__, 'header_script' ) );

            // adds the captcha to the custom login form
            add_action( 'custom_captcha_login', array( __CLASS__, 'display_captcha' ) );

            // authenticate the captcha answer
            add_action( 'custom_authenticate_user', array( __CLASS__, 'validate_captcha_custom_login' ), 10, 2 );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify the captcha answer
     *
     * @param $user string login username
     * @param $password string login password
     *
     * @return WP_Error|WP_user
     */

    public static function validate_captcha_custom_login( $user, $password ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {}
        $error_msg .= 'I want to show this message';
        return false;
    }

}
```

I have also tried the following

```
    public static function validate_captcha_custom_login( $user, $password ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {}

        $error_msg .= 'I want to show this message';
        return false;
    }
```

The following is the login form template page the other plugin uses

```
{if $action == 'login'}
    {if !empty($msg_ve)}
        <p class="message">{$msg_ve}</p>
    {/if}
    <form method="post" action="{if !empty($login_url)}{$login_url}{/if}" id="loginform" name="loginform">
        {if !empty($somefields)}{$somefields}{/if}
        {if !empty($error_msg)}
            <p class="message wpc_error">{$error_msg}</p>
        {/if}
        {if !empty($custom_login_error_msg)}
            <p class="message wpc_error">{$custom_login_error_msg}</p>
        {/if}
        <p>
            <label for="user_login">{if !empty($labels.username)}{$labels.username}{/if}<br>
            <input type="text" tabindex="10" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_login" name="log"></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="user_pass">{if !empty($labels.password)}{$labels.password}{/if}<br>
            <input type="password" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_pass" name="pwd"></label>
        </p>
        {do_action( 'custom_captcha_login' )}
        <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input type="checkbox" tabindex="90" value="forever" id="rememberme" name="rememberme"> {if !empty($labels.remember)}{$labels.remember}{/if}</label></p>
        <p class="submit">
            <label>
                <input type="submit" tabindex="100" value="Log In" class="button-primary" id="wp-submit" name="wp-submit">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="redirect_to">
            </label>
        </p>

        {if isset($lostpassword_href) && !empty($lostpassword_href)}
        <p id="nav">
            <label>
                <a title="Password Lost and Found" href="{$lostpassword_href}">Lost your password?</a>
            </label>
        </p>
        {/if}
    </form>
{elseif $action == 'lostpassword' && isset($lostpassword_href) && !empty($lostpassword_href) }
    <form method="post" action="{if !empty($login_url)}{$login_url}{/if}" id="loginform" name="loginform">
        {if !empty($error_msg)}
            <p class="message wpc_error">{$error_msg}</p>
        {/if}
        <p>
            <label for="user_login">{if !empty($labels.email)}{$labels.email}{/if}<br>
            <input type="text" tabindex="10" size="35" value="" class="input" id="user_login" name="user_login"></label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <label>
                <input type="submit" tabindex="100" value="{if !empty($labels.get_new_password)}{$labels.get_new_password}{/if}" class="button button-primary button-large" id="wp-submit" name="wp-submit">
            </label>
        </p>
        <p id="nav">
            <label>
                <a title="Back to Login Page" href="{$login_href}">Remember your password?</a>
            </label>
        </p>
    </form>
{elseif ( $action == 'rp' || $action == 'resetpass' ) && !empty($lostpassword_href) }
    <form method="post" action="{if !empty($login_url)}{$login_url}{/if}" id="loginform" name="loginform">
        {if !empty($error_msg)}
            <p class="message wpc_error">{$error_msg}</p>
        {/if}
        {if !in_array($error_msg, $check_invalid)}
            <input type="hidden" id="user_login" value="{if !empty($user_login)}{$user_login}{/if}" autocomplete="off" />
            <p>
                <label for="pass1">{if !empty($labels.new_password)}{$labels.new_password}{/if}<br />
                <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="input" size="35" value="" autocomplete="off" /></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="pass2">{if !empty($labels.confirm_new_password)}{$labels.confirm_new_password}{/if}<br />
                <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" class="input" size="35" value="" autocomplete="off" /></label>
            </p>

            <div id="pass-strength-result">{if !empty($labels.strength_indicator)}{$labels.strength_indicator}{/if}</div>
            <p class="description indicator-hint">{if !empty($labels.hint_indicator)}{$labels.hint_indicator}{/if}</p>
            <br class="clear" />
            <p class="submit"><label><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="{if !empty($labels.reset_password)}{$labels.reset_password}{/if}" /></label>
            </p>
        </form>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

Comment: Have tried a few things but nothing seems to work `  if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {
  
  die();
  }
  
  
  else {  
  // Let User Pass
  return $user;
  }`

Comment: You just need to pass the error message ??  Or any problems with captha?

Comment: Yes I cant seem to pass an error message and stop the validation if it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this is working for me.

In validation

```
if(validationfunctions failed)
{
$error_msg .= '<p class="error">I want to show this message</p>';
return false;
}
```

and in page

```
if (!empty($error_msg)) {
echo $error_msg;
}
```

Do not set error message inside function.

Comment: The page is run off a WP template page build using php expressions like this `{if !empty($custom_login_error_msg)}
            <p class="message wpc_error">{echo $custom_login_error_msg}</p>
        {/if}`

Comment: `{echo $custom_login_error_msg}` caused the template to fail to load so I had to use `{$custom_login_error_msg}`

Comment: Tried both `public static function validate_captcha_custom_login( $user, $password ) {
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {

   $error_msg .= '<p class="error">I want to show this message</p>';
   return false;
   }` ------ and ----- `public static function validate_captcha_custom_login( $user, $password ) {
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {}
  $error_msg .= '<p class="error">I want to show this message</p>';
  return false;
 }` ------ Both didnt seem to show an error message

Comment: This is on the template page ` {if !empty($custom_login_error_msg)}
            <p class="message wpc_error">{$custom_login_error_msg}</p>
        {/if}`

Comment: even just putting `<p class="message wpc_error">{$custom_login_error_msg}</p>` into the template and trying to process the validation shows nothing but the core templates `<p class="message wpc_error">{$error_msg}</p>` shows its error message?

Comment: piping the message right into `$error_msg` also didnt seem to work. `public static function validate_captcha_custom_login( $user, $password ) {
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {}
  $error_msg .= 'I want to show this message';
  return false;
 }`

Comment: In the longrun the validation does work and it does stop the user from logging in... and lets them pass if the validation passes ... only glitch is that I cant get a fail message to get passed into the template page no matter what I seem to do?

Comment: Update org question with full code for both my custom login page and the plugins template page

Comment: If you mean like this `  if ( ! isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) || ! self::captcha_verification() ) {}$error_msg .= 'I want to show this message';
   return false;}` I have tried it and it also does not pop the message

Comment: You can't pass error message from function to page. Instead put your function inside if loop and set error message in page itself. If (function ()) return false, set error message.

Comment: If(validate_captcha_custom_login($user,$pass)){$error_msg ="too";} try this way

Comment: if(validate_captcha_custom_login($user,$pass)){$error_msg ="too";} comes up as a syntax error

Comment: I gave an example. Try your function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90709/discussion-between-webmaster-alex-l-and-subin-thomas).

Comment: If your still willing to help iv left some updated code in the chatroom